# Poco c++ How to read "text" data type from PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: c++, postgresql, poco-libraries

I am executing a database (`PostgreSQL`) query.
`Сomment` column has "text" data type.

`SELECT Comment FROM table WHERE id = 1;`

```
RecordSet result = query->execute("");
bool more = result .moveFirst();

while (more)
{
  std::string comment = result["Comment"].convert<std::string>());
  or
  std::string comment = result["Comment"].extract<std::string>());

  more = result.moveNext();
}
```

I get an exception

> Poco::SQL::UnknownTypeException

How can I read a field without changing the database data type?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out

`Poco::SQL::MetaColumn::ColumnDataType type = result.columnType("Comment");`

type is Poco::SQL::MetaColumn::ColumnDataType::FDT_CLOB

`Poco::SQL::CLOB comment = response["Comment"].extract<Poco::SQL::CLOB>();`

Look the same https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2566 if POCO version < 1.9.1